# How to enable/disable browsing of properties only for a single instance of a class, not for all instances?

Tags: c#, user-interface, properties

```
public class BaseFilter
{
    private bool _enableFliter;
    private int _setMinTo;
    private int _setMinFrom;
    private string _name;

    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public bool EnableFilter 
    {
        get => _enableFliter;
        set
        {
            if (_enableFliter != value)
            {
                SetBrowsableAttributeValue(nameof(SetMinFrom), value);
                SetBrowsableAttributeValue(nameof(SetMinTo), value);
            }
            _enableFliter = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "min from")]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int SetMinFrom { get => _setMinFrom; set { _setMinFrom = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "min to")]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int SetMinTo { get => _setMinTo; set { _setMinTo = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public BaseFilter(string argname)
    {
        _enableFliter = false;
        _setMinTickFrom = 0;
        _setMinTickTo = 0;
        _name = argname;
    }

    private void SetBrowsableAttributeValue(string attribute, object value)
    {
        var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType())[attribute];
        //var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[attribute];
        var attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
        var isBrow = attrib.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.Contains("browsable", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        isBrow.SetValue(attrib, value);
    }
}
```

When I create instances of the base class above within another class as follows:

```
public class Myxyz
{
    public BaseFilter Day { get; set; } = new("Day");
    public BaseFilter Week { get; set; } = new("Week");
    ...
}
```

Enabling of property `Day` will also show all properties of property `Week` like `SetMinFrom` and `SetMinTo` when I just enable property `Day`. What do I have to change the code so that browsing of properties is limited to the object that is enabled/disabled?

E.g. if `Day` is enabled, I will only see `SetMinFrom` and `SetMinTo` that belongs to `Day`.

Comment: My first guess would be to investigate the other values of `RefreshProperties`' constants/ Enum values outside `All`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. I think what needs to be done here is to make clear that only the properties of the instance are to be updated. The question is how to do that.